# ¿Cómo traducir "Stacks" en un contexto de programación?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico, solicitud-de-término, informática, terminología

Estoy leyendo un libro de programación, y tengo duda en como traducir **Stacks** en un contexto de programación.

Busqué una traducción a la palabra y me lo traduce como *apilar, pilas, amontonar, estanteria, estante*. La cosa es que no se que palabra quedaria mejor.

Aquí está el contexto que se maneja:

> Chapter 20 Lists, **Stacks**, Queues, and Priority Queues

¿Qué traducción sería la más correcta en un contexto de programación?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

En el contexto de programación, un *stack* se podría traducir como *pila* (en el concepto de grupo de ítems puestos uno encima de otro).

Lo que caracteriza a un *stack* de otras agrupaciones de ítems es que:

- los datos están ordenados según se insertan.
- la única forma de añadir o quitar ítems es siempre por el mismo "extremo" del orden, de forma que el último ítem que hayas añadido será el primero que extraigas.

Por ejemplo

1. Pila vacía ->
2. Añades<sup>1</sup> `a` -> `a`
3. Añades `b` -> `a, b`
4. Añades `c` -> `a, b, c`
5. Eliminas un elemento<sup>2</sup> -> `a, b`

Nota que en ningún momento se puede especificar dónde haces la inserción o qué elemento eliminas; eso te viene definido por la definición de cómo se comporta un *stack*

---

<sup>1</sup>: En términos informáticos es la operación *push* (apilar).

<sup>2</sup>: Es la operación *pop* desapilar.

Comment: Nunca vi otro término que pila para traducir stack. Es el que se usaba en la Lic. en Informática en la UNLP (Arg.) si mal no recuerdo, y en varios libro de lenguajes de programación. Y si no recuerdo mal, el término _stack_ fue acuñado por analogía con una _pila_ de platos o bandejas en una cafetería.

Comment: Las operaciones sobre las pilas son:
•"Push": introducir, insertar, cargar. 
•"Pop": extraer, sacar, rebajar.

Eso es lo que a mi me enseñaron.

Comment: En los 80's, los terminos usados en las profesiones informáticas en México eran Pilas y Colas para referirse a Stacks y Queues. Las operaciones eran Insertar y Extraer, como se señala arriba.

Answer (score 5):

En el contexto de programación *stack* se traduce habitualmente como [*pila*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pila_(inform%C3%A1tica)) con el significado de su primera acepción según el diccionario de la [RAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Sz7DDE4%7CSz7PRrG):

> **pila**
>
> Del lat. pila 'columna'.
>
> 1. f. Montón, rimero o cúmulo que se hace poniendo una sobre otra las piezas o porciones de que consta algo. Pila de lana, de ladrillos.

Comment: Si se me permite una pequeña digresión. Hace años estuve dando unos cursos de C en Lisboa (Portugal). Mi portugués es pobre (para que decir otra cosa) por lo que los cursos se dieron en español. Para los clientes en España procuraba traducir todos los términos, e hice lo mismo en Portugal. Al llegar a *queu y stack* hable de cola y pila. Al día siguiente, en un descanso, pregunte si se enteraban, si todo iba bien. Todo era correcto salvo, ¿salvo que?, pues que pila en portugués es, eso, "lo de los chicos", mientras me señalaban hacia abajo. A partir de entonces *stack y queue*, por supuesto.

Comment: El nombre que damos a las 'pilas' de las linternas, radios portátiles, mandos de la TV, etc. viene del descubrimiento del señor Alejandro Volta. Volta apiló discos de cobre y de cinc alternados, que llevan intercalados un paño humedeciendo con un ácido. Esta "pila de discos" empieza y termina con discos de diferente tipo. Al conectar  los discos situados en los extremos se obtiene un flujo eléctrico.

Comment: @JLPrieto: +1 Información interesante para no meter la pata con colaboradores de habla portuguesa ;)

Answer (score 0):

**stack** (Fuente: Oxford Dictionary [1](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stack))

> noun: stack; plural noun: stacks
>
> 1. a pile of objects, typically one that is neatly arranged. *A stack of boxes*

**pila** (Fuente: Diccionario de la Real Academia Española [2](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Sz7DDE4))

> Del lat. pila 'columna'.
>
> 1. f. Montón, rimero o cúmulo que se hace poniendo una sobre otra las piezas o porciones de que consta algo. *Pila de lana, de ladrillos.*